# video problem with Xubuntu/Lubuntu 17.10 and Acer Aspire One

Tags: video, aspire

Something really strange happens to me on my Acer Aspire One (Intel Atom N270 1.60 GHz, 1 GB of DDR2 RAM, 16 GB HD SSD).

I have installed Xubuntu 16.04 and it worked very well. After 1 year I decided to replace it with Lubuntu 17.10 hoping to speed it up a little bit.

I proceed with the boot (with the Live DVD) of Lubuntu 17.10 and everything works for the best. I pass to the installation on the HD that proceeds without errors until the end.

At the reboot the system rises and is alive but the screen appears for 4/5 on the left black with indecipherable writings and apparentement normal on the remaining 1/5 on the right side. Not possible any action on the system. There is obviously a problem on the video drive.

I repeat everything with Lubuntu 16.04 and everything works. Repeat everything with Xubuntu 17.10 and the problem is identical again.

At this point it seems obvious that the issues are the 17.xx versions of both Lubuntu and Xubuntu.

One thing I do not understand. Why if I boot with the Live versions of both Xubuntu/Lubuntu 17.10 everything works perfectly but when I proceed with the installation on the HD the video problem arises? I beleave that the graphic chip is the Intel 945GME.

Many thanks to anyone that comes with a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert on ubuntu but I had the same issue.
The following thread solved the issue for me:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2376624&page=2

This is what I did:

edit /etc/default/grub and add this line in the end of file
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text

sudo update-grub

reboot

Comment: Please provide small instruction from linked page.

Comment: This is what I did:
edit /etc/default/grub and add this line in the end of file
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
sudo update-grub
reboot

Comment: In answer, not here.

Comment: ok, moved it to the answer

Comment: I don't know why this has been downvoted, but in my case this fixed the problem. Just in case you are wondering how to modify /etc/default/grub, enter in recovery mode from the grub menu and launch a root session. Then make the file-system read-write by remounting it with `mount -o rw,remount /`.

Comment: Had the same issue with my Asus netbook. It is now solved! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had serious problems with XUBUNTU 17.1 graphics and my old ATI 1300/1550 card when I selected a different screen resolution.  After that upon login the screen would freeze. I could bypass the problem by using rescue boot but there was no ability to change the video card resolution through the display settings panel, or by xrandr terminal commands.

The solution for me was one from 8 years past and very simple, once I stumbled onto it.  **Hit alt-ctrl-F8 , screen goes black, then alt-ctrl-F7 and a fully functional screen appears** .  All lock up resolved itself, all screen resolutions appeared in the display settings panel.

This is not a permanent fix, but is so simple as to be acceptable until the bugs in 17.1 are worked out.  I present this information because it surely indicates that whatever this flaw in the system interface with the video card driver is, it is very minor and likely easy to fix.  The fact that it has occurred before back in 2010 and was fixed may point to a solution.

Jimmy Johnson

Answer (score 0):

Same problem using Xubuntu 18.04 on an Acer Aspire One Cloudbook 11 (AO1-131-C58K).
If you boot from a USB Stick push <kbd>E</kbd> on your keyboard before selecting that you want to use Xubuntu Live. In the menu replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`.
Then push <kbd>F10</kbd>.